# Can't install memcached on XAMPP with PHP 7.4.3

Tags: php, xampp, memcached

I'm at a loss.

I tried every single instruction on the internet, I can't seem to  install and run memcached on my xampp server.

I'm using a mac. I installed memcached via brew and updated the php.ini file with `extension=memcached.so`

When I check with `phpinfo();` I see that there is no memcached installed.

Could someone please instruct me from the very beginning the steps I needed to take in order to run this on my local with xampp? Or hint me what I'm missing?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you restart server and php?

Comment: Yes i did. I feel like I'm missing to install something.